# Call Azure AD secured web api from SharePoint online page using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, adal

1. I have a Web API secured with Azure AD
2. SharePoint online tenant is also authenticated against same Azure AD
3. I want to call the Web API from a page in SPO using Angular

By the time the page is loaded the user is already authenticated against the Azure AD. So I want to enable SSO for this web api call.

Appreciate if someone can share a sample code or any direction on how to achieve this. I have seen some samples using ADAL, but I don't think this scenario is addressed in those samples.